# Where's the code for Laravel's built-in validators?

Tags: laravel, validation

Where is the code for Laravel's built-in validators?

I want to edit Laravel's validators `after` and `before` date formats that is used to compare the field dates.

Comment: Instead of editing the vendor files, it would be better to use https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#custom-validation-rules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though this is not some code based question but I would like to answer it.

If you are looking to modify Laravel's validators `after` and `before` date formats, then consider using custom validator functions to achieve the same.

There are few reasons to it:

1. Though Laravel is open source and you can modify them as per your requirement, but that was required when Laravel didn't provide extension functionalities for some of it batteries.
2. If you change the implementation internally, then you would have to ship the entire `vendor` directory along with your codebase. Which is not good, there are thousands of file inside `vendor` directory.
3. Changing the implementation internally will cause confusion for fellow developers. The Laravel's documentation will say `X` but your own implementation will perform 'Y'.